# How to verify user's name and password in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, authentication, passwords

Given a user's name and password, is there a way to check if the name is a valid user account on the system and if the supplied password matches the password for that user's account?

---

**Edit:** The need for this arises from the way authentication is structured in this application. The app uses the local accounts on the system to allow the users to remotely access files and stuff. My app needs a way of authenticating those users to provide them with access to its services.

Comment: Can you give _any_ more information about how this will be used? You could use the `net` command for instance, if you were testing a single one by hand. That would make this a SU problem. You could use something in the IIS configs if you were using a website and ASP.NET. You could use some of the .NET libraries if you were writing a desktop app. ~ There's always remote desktopping into the system / sitting at the keyboard and trying to login.

Comment: @drachenstern: Okay, I guess I was kind of vague... I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use the [LogonUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184.aspx) API for this purpose... If the call fails, then either the username or password are bogus.

Comment: Use `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` if you just want to verify the username/password and don't need to impersonate them or anything.